# gdb stops in a command file if there is an error. How to continue despite the error?

Tags: linux, gdb, coredump

I my real gdb script while analyzing a core file I try to dereference a pointer and get "Error in sourced command file: Cannot access memory at address " and then my gdb script stops. What I want is just to go on executing my gdb script without stopping. Is it possible?

This is a test program and a test gdb script that demonstrates my problem. In this situation the pointer has NULL value but in a real situation the pointer will like have not null invalid value.

This is test C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct my_struct {
  int v1;
  int v2;
};

int main()
{
  my_struct *p;
  printf("%d %d\n", p->v1, p->v2);
  return 0;
}
```

This is a test gdb script:

```
>cat analyze.gdb
p p->v1
q
```

And this is demonstration of the problem (what I want from gdb here is to get this error message and then go process `quit` command):

```
>gdb -silent a.out ./core.22384 -x ./analyze.gdb
Reading symbols from /a.out...done.
[New Thread 22384]
Core was generated by `./a.out'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x0000000000400598 in main () at main.cpp:11
11        printf("%d %d\n", p->v1, p->v2);
./analyze.gdb:1: Error in sourced command file:
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.12-1.80.el6.x86_64
```

---

**Update**

Thanks to Tom. This is a gdb script that handles this problem:

```
>cat ./analyze.v2.gdb
python
def my_ignore_errors(arg):
  try:
    gdb.execute("print \"" + "Executing command: " + arg + "\"")
    gdb.execute (arg)
  except:
    gdb.execute("print \"" + "ERROR: " + arg + "\"")
    pass

my_ignore_errors("p p")
my_ignore_errors("p p->v1")
gdb.execute("quit")
```

This is how it works:

```
>gdb -silent ./a.out -x ./analyze.v2.gdb -c ./core.15045
Reading symbols from /import/home/a.out...done.
[New Thread 15045]
Core was generated by `./a.out'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x0000000000400598 in main () at main.cpp:11
11        printf("%d %d\n", p->v1, p->v2);
$1 = "Executing command: p p"
$2 = (my_struct *) 0x0
$3 = "Executing command: p p->v1"
$4 = "ERROR: p p->v1"
$5 = "Executing command: quit"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

gdb's command language doesn't have a way to ignore an error when processing a command.

This is easily done, though, if your gdb was built with the Python extension.  Search for the "ignore-errors" script.  With that, you can:

(gdb) ignore-errors print *foo

... and any errors from print will be shown but not abort the rest of your script.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I did't managed to make use of `ignore-errors` since I get `Undefined command: "ignore-errors"` but I created a similar command and I worked.

Comment: Yeah, you had to search for it.  http://sourceware.org/ml/gdb/2010-06/msg00100.html

Comment: Let me explain. In gdb on my server there ignore-errors.py but I don't know yet how to use it. Simply entering `ignore-errors print p` does not work. Nevertheless I made use of the idea in the ignore-errors.py and created my own `my_ignore_errors`. You can see it in my updated question.

Comment: You can just "source ignore-errors.py".  That will register the "ignore-errors" command.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this:

```
gdb a.out < analyze.v2.gdb
```

This will execute the commands in analyze.v2.gdb line by line, even if an error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to exit if any error occurs, you can use the [`-batch` gdb option](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Mode-Options.html):

> Run in batch mode. Exit with status `0` after processing all the command
>   files specified with ‘`-x`’ (and all commands from initialization files,
>   if not inhibited with ‘`-n`’). Exit with nonzero status if an error
>   occurs in executing the `GDB` commands in the command files. [...]